# setLastModified date with Qt

Tags: c++, qt, qt4, posix

I need to set the last modified date for some files.  It is an essential ability for my application.

I don't see how I can do this with QT.  I don't see a method/function for it.
I can read the dates with Qt but I don't see how I can set the dates.

Now... I know some (I think all actually) windows API's from MS have this ability.

The thing is that I am not looking for a "Windows" only solution.  I need this ability to work on Windows, Linux, and Mac. This is why I choose Qt...

Any solution proposed should be API centric (don't want a system command/utility) and the solution should cover the 3 main OS's (Win,Linux,Mac).

Comment: Did you find a solution? I have same problem.
Is it possible using Qt?.
Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The posix function for this is [utime(2)](http://linux.die.net/man/2/utime), which is also available on windows as part of MSVCRT (see [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4wacf567%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)). So using that should cover Mac, Linux, and Windows.

Since [QAbstractFileEngine](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7/qabstractfileengine.html#fileTime) doesn't expose this functionality, I don't think it'll be available in any other Qt filesystem APIs either.

Answer (score 4):

In windows include `qt_windows.h` and play with modified and creation date.

```
QDateTime newModifiedTime=ui->dateTimeEdit_modified->dateTime();
QDateTime newCreationDate=TimeEdit_Creation->dateTime();
FILETIME pmodifiedtime,pcreationtime;
    HANDLE hfile;
    LPCWSTR filename=Filename.toStdWString().c_str();
          hfile=CreateFile(filename,GENERIC_READ|GENERIC_WRITE,0,NULL,OPEN_EXISTING,FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL,NULL);
    if(hfile==INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
    {
        QMessageBox::information(this,"Failed","Unable to open file,check file permission");
    }
    else
    {
        LONGLONG ll = Int32x32To64(newCreationDate.toTime_t(), 10000000) + 116444736000000000;
        pcreationtime.dwLowDateTime = (DWORD) ll;
        pcreationtime.dwHighDateTime = ll >> 32;
        LONGLONG ll2 = Int32x32To64(newModifiedTime.toTime_t(), 10000000) + 116444736000000000;
        pmodifiedtime.dwLowDateTime = (DWORD) ll2;
        pmodifiedtime.dwHighDateTime = ll2 >> 32;

        if(!SetFileTime(hfile,&pcreationtime,NULL,&pmodifiedtime))
        {
           QMessageBox::information(this,"Failed","Unable to set Date And Time");
        }
        else
        {
           QMessageBox::information(this,"Success","Date And Time Updated");
           ui->lineEdit_FileName->clear();
        }
    }
    CloseHandle(hfile);
```

For linux add include `utime.h` and `fcntl.h` then

```
struct utimbuf timebuffer;
timebuffer.modtime=newModifiedTime.toTime_t();
const char *filename=Filename.toAscii();
if((utime(filename,&timebuffer))<0)
{
        QMessageBox::information(this,"Error","Unable to set Time");
}
else
{
        QMessageBox::information(this,"Success","Date Changed");
}
```

Comment: `LPCWSTR filename=Filename.toStdWString().c_str();` is a very bad advice, because `filename` will store the pointer to deleted temporary object

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is anything specific. Easiest way is probably to open the file for write+append and the close it again - this lets the OS/Filesystem update the modified time.

You could also try reading the permissions and calling setPerimssions, that's sometimes used as a safer way of updating a file since it's non-blocking.

edit: to set an arbitrary last modified time you could use - on windows [SetFileTime](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724933%28VS.85%29.aspx) function.

There is a   `boost::filesystem::last_write_time( )` you migth want to look at - I haven't used it.

Comment: That would not work at all.  If dateTime now is B, I copy a file that was last modified at dateTime A, the copy will have modified dateTime of B.  Down the road, as time passes, dateTime will be C. If at that time I open and save the file as you suggest it will have a last modified dateTime of C.  Obviously this is pointless as the lastModified dataTime will be even more "off" because I need it to be A and not C.  I need the lastModified dateTime to be the same as the original file.

Comment: Sorry ? - you set the last modified time to 'now' and you do this by modifying the file 'now' !

Comment: I don't want to set the last modified time to 'now'.  Hence, what you suggest will not work.  All MS API's allow the setting of file time stamps as does Java and other mature API's.  Qt can get time stamps but can't set time stamps as far as I know.  If I have to I'll use the WinAPI but that leaves me in the dark with regards to Linux and MAC.

Comment: I want to preserve the time stamps of my original file in the copy... specifically in regards to the last modification time stamp.

Comment: I actually need the "now" option and I tried this. I'm working on Windows with Qt 5.6. Opening the file for write + append and closing it without actually writing anything did not update the last modified timestamp for me. So far, I haven't found a solution that's cross-platform using Qt's classes.